# CSS for divs within a .Net repeater

Tags: asp.net, css, html, repeater

I have an asp repeater that is inserting x amount of divs. The content within these divs can vary in vertical length and therefore the repeater currently displays a tabular row like structure.

I was hoping someone may have some ideas as to how I can style the repeater content so that each repeater item appears directly underneath the one above it no matter the length.

So at present my repeater outputs.

```
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3
       Item2 Item3
       Item2 Item3
             Item3

Item4 Item5  Item6
Item4 Item5  Item6
Item4 Item5  Item6
```

Where as I need it to output:

```
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3
Item1  Item2 Item3       
Item4  Item2 Item3
Item4  Item5 Item3
Item4  Item5 Item6
Item4  Item5 Item6
Item4  Item5 Item6
```

I hope that makes sense. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
 <asp:repeater ID="rpItems" runat="server"><HeaderTemplate><div style=""></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="divImg">
            <asp:Literal ID="litImage" runat="server" />            
            <div class="divImgInfo">
                <p>                                
                    <asp:Literal ID="litTitle" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                </p>
                <p>    
                    <div style="font-size: 11px; color: #919191;" >
                        <asp:Literal ID="litItemPrice" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Literal ID="litItemComments" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" />                                                                        
                    </div>                                                                                               
                </p>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></div></FooterTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

CSS

```
.divImg { width: 170px; margin: 0px 0 0 0;   background-color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 3px; }
.divImg img { max-width: 150px; padding: 8px; }
.divImgOverlay {position:relative;margin-top:0;padding:0 18px 0 6px;display:none;height:0;max-height:38px;overflow:hidden;}
.divImgInfo {padding:0px 1px 0 10px; }
.divImgInfo div {margin:0 0 0 0; }
```

Comment: This isn't a css issue, it's the layout of your HTML. Please post your HTML.

Comment: Not sure there's a css solution for this, unless the content is static.  You'll probably need a js fix, something like http://masonry.desandro.com/, though that may be overkill.

Comment: Thanks all. I've posted content above

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: If you say they will only vary in vertical length you can consider defining some larger divs to work as columns and let the elements replicate vertically within them (being positioned by float: left).

Then you can append a column identifier to the id of each div and then set the style for them and try to manipulate the look-and-feel so you keep the tabular structure that you want, i.e., distributing heights.

```
<div class="divImg_column<x>">
    ...
```